# Sqlite3 Concurrency Issue in IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using SQLite 3 in my iOS application. It requires lots of read/write operation and many of them attempted concurrently. Most of these functions are running in separate threads, however accessing same database.

Here are few methods I have thought of:

1. At every database access ( read/write ) I put a flag as `database_open=YES`, and if it is found true I retry again in few seconds. I can put the function at the database layer itself.
2. Run all database operations in same thread. However, my use case is such that I need to wait for some HTTP calls to finish and store the retreived data into SQLite. For this method, I will have to make all these server calls as well synchronous. Not the best idea.

Please suggest if I am thinking in wrong direction.

Comment: offtopic:you should give [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) a try. FMDB is thread save and has a really simple interface for SQL statements

Comment: Or, to be more precise, you can use FMDB's `FMDatabaseQueue`, as a mechanism for coordinating database interactions from different threads by having a separate serial queue which the two threads will dispatch any database interaction. Even if you don't use FMDB, you can employ this pattern to coordinating database interactions from different threads, having your own serial queue to which you'll dispatch all those interactions.

Comment: Thanks Guys. This seem to solve my problem. I read their FMDatabaseQueue, it does exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite [supports concurrent access from multiple threads](http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html). Simply configure the SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD mode, and separately open the database from each of the threads.